# Studying for Zend 5.3 certification

Tags: php, certificate

I decided to give the Zend exam, and currently studying hard.

The topics I learned are based on the [Exam Information](http://www.zend.com/services/certification/php-5-certification/) on the official website, and the [Study Guide](http://www.zend.com/topics/PHP-5-3-Study-Guide-v1.pdf), and as materials I use the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php)

I noticed pretty much no question about emails (except one that is related to security), is this topic too small to be mentioned, or will there actually be no questions regarding emails ?

On the flip side, there are, I think, hundreds of extensions I never worked with and probably never will (audio/video manipulation, windows only extensions, etc).

So, how complete are these documents ? Should I only study the topics in the study guide, or should I go all the way with every little thing that's partially related to the subject ?

Comment: ZCE isn't all about knowing every detail of every extension that exists, it's about knowing how to manipulte data (strings, numerics, arrays) in PHP, about writing functions and variable scope, about how to define classes and call methods, etc... basically the focus is on core, with limited extras such as databases (in general terms) and html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to study the 10 topics from the study guide. But you need to study them well. Try to learn as many idiosyncrasies surrounding each of the topic areas as you can.

As already mentioned, there is little to no emphasis on email, and there will be no questions regarding audio, video etc.